# Need form to check all fields for validation when I only one field

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular 8 the current validation only check for validation the field you are currently modifying, I need to angular to recheck all fields since some fields validation depends on other field values. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Can you please add some code and point out where exactly you are facing the issue ?

Comment: What did you try? + The question is not clear - *current validation only check for validation* how it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to implement the [ValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn) interface:

```
interface ValidatorFn {    
  (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null 
}
```

Here is a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cross-validation),